# Setting up username/password authentication with EC2 for mongodb on port 27017

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I currently have an EC2 instance that I am using to host my mongodb sever on from port 27017. Previously I had just setup the security group to just use my home IP address to authenticate a TCP connection to port 27017, however I no longer have a static IP. I now have one that changes everyday that I cannot control. Is there a way to create a mongo URI like mongolabs has

```
mongodb://<username><passs>@<my EC2 IP>:27017/db
```

that I can use to connect from PyMongo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many [guides](https://www.mkyong.com/mongodb/mongodb-authentication-example/) available by searching that describe how to enable MongoDB authentication.

Alternatively, you could create a small script that uses the AWS CLI to update the security group with your current IP address. The script could be run when needed or set to run automatically your computer starts or you log in.

Answer (score 1):

Install AWS CLI on your machine. You should have proper IAM permissions to update the security group. Then you can use below bash script to update your security group with your current IP address.

```
#!/bin/bash
ip = 'curl -s http://whatismijnip.nl |cut -d " " -f 5'
sleep 5
aws ec2 authorize-security-group-ingress --group-name MySecurityGroup --protocol tcp --port 22 --cidr $ip/24
```